# In Python3 How to make a user defined class object can get element by index ( obj[ i ] )?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, overriding, iterable

In python, list, string, tuple can be got element by using index (obj[i]), just like C++. In the same way is there any method like override operators to make user-defined class' object be able to get element by using square-bracket []?

For example:

```
>>>obj = user_class([1,2,4])
>>>obj[0]
1
>>>obj[1]
2
```

the way `user_class=list` or `user_class=tuple` can't be a solution, because I have to add a series of control code in this this class. And the way that this class work is totally different from list or tuple.

Is there anyone know the solution?

Comment: Add a [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method in the class.

Comment: Use `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__` magic methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method in the `user_class`.

```
class user_class:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.values = lst
    def __getitem__(self, it):
        return self.values[it]
```

Or it can be a subclass of some base type like list:

```
class user_class(list):
    # your control code goes here
    def shout(self):
        print("AAA!")
```